# ACF repeater - show the first 10 rows and put the others in another div

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

I've created a list of logos with ACF repeater field. I'd like to have the 10 first logos displayed in my template and the others in an expand collapse. I've almost managed to make it work but the problem is that it's creating an expand collapse every 10 entries while I only want to have 1 containing everything after 10.

```
  <div class="row"><!-- open first .row -->
      <?php

        while (have_rows('partenaires')) {
          the_row();
                        $partner_image = get_sub_field('logo_partenaire');
          if (($count%10) == 0 && $count > 0) { ?>
            </div><!-- close last .row -->
          </div><!-- close last .section -->

                            <a role="button" class="text-center" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsePartners" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsePartners"><?php _e( 'Et bien d\'autres', 'oleandre' ); ?></a>

          <div class="collapse" id="collapsePartners"><!-- open next .section -->
            <div class="row"><!-- open next .row -->
            <?php

          } // end if 10
          ?>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $partner_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $partner_image['alt'] ?>" />
                                </div>
            </div>
          <?php

          // increment count
          $count++;

        } // end while have_rows
      ?>
    </div><!-- close last .row -->
  </div><!-- close lase .section -->
  <?php

   } // end if have_rows
 ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: `get_row_index()` gives you the row number, `get_row_index() == 10` should be start of collapse etc.

Comment: `($count%10) == 0` is the same as saying, "does 10 go equeally into the number" , So 20,30 etc will also be true in that condition

Comment: Ok but doesn't get_row_index only display the row number ? Not sure what I can do with it.

Comment: Well yes, don't you want to start a collapse at row 10 and onwards?

Comment: Indeed but I'm not connecting the dots here...